# Creating Tables in Db2 involving a With Clause

Tags: db2, create-table, with-statement

I'm trying to a table view in DB2 but Its returning an error

My code involves a WITH clause as well so I'm not sure if this is part of it

My Code looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME_FINAL AS
WITH Q1 AS ( SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONDITION = X) SELECT * FROM Q1
```

I have obviously simplified it but there is a need for the with clause

Also, how do I ensure this table is placed in a specific table space?

I also had problems when I tried to do it like:

```
CREATE TABLE DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME_FINAL (COLUMNNAME INT) IN TABLE_SPACE_NAME;
INSERT INTO DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME_FINAL
WITH Q1 AS ( SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONDITION = X) SELECT COLUMNNAME FROM Q1;
```

Answer (score 1):

These forms both work for me:

```
CREATE TABLE MYLIB.MYDATA1 as (
    with MD as ( select * from mylib.mydata )
        select * from MD
) with no data
;
```

And:

```
INSERT INTO MYLIB.MYDATA1
    with MD as ( select * from mylib.mydata )
       select * from MD
;
```

But I don't know what might (or might not) work for you. You need to tell us what platform and DB2 version/release you're running.

Comment: I'm trying to run this with a chained `WITH table_a as (...), table_b as (...) ... table_n as (...)`  structure and I keep getting `ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD WITH`. Is this not possible for chained with sub-queries?